# How to Loop Thread.sleep() statement , until Specified Element Found in Selenium Webdriver using Java

Tags: java, selenium

i want to loop Thread.sleep() statement , until specified element found, i dont want to give a specified Time in Thread.sleep() statement, instead of that i want to loop thread.sleep . so that it should keep on checking the element for every second, if the element found then it should break the loop.

can anyone please help me in this ??

Comment: _i dont want to give a specified Time in Thread.sleep()_ and _every second_. What do you want to happen, **exactly**?

Comment: I've removed the `multithreading` tag as it doesn't seem relevant.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to wait for an Element to be present or visible use [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) along with [ExpectedConditions](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html)

> Wait will ignore instances of NotFoundException that are encountered
>   (thrown) by default in the 'until' condition, and immediately
>   propagate all others. You can add more to the ignore list by calling
>   ignoring(exceptions to add).

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);//timeout in Seconds
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("xpath"))).click();
```

Comment: Thanks madhan, but i have already checked by using webdriver wait also with all possible six methods, still it is not working , so i want to use a thread.sleep for that, do you have solution for looping thread.sleep()???

Comment: @SumanthUrs Increase the wait time to more seconds like 120 seconds or 240 seconds.Why do you want Thread.Sleep anyway

Comment: webdriver wait is not working so i am using thread.sleep(), suppose i have given a time of 5 sec, if the element found in 3 sec then it should skip remaining 2 sec and perform the action. it should not wait for 5 sec , so i want to loop the condition.. is there any solution for this?? instead of webdriver wait

Comment: Webdriver wait work likes that only as soon as the element is found it will move on..It wont wait for whole time

Comment: @SumanthUrs And have you checked that whether the element is present in a frame or something

Comment: <button id="__button0" class="hamBurgerIcon-style sapMBarChild sapMBtn sapMBtnBase" aria-pressed="false" data-sap-ui="__button0" type="button">    ..        this is the tag, for element id, webdriver wait is not working , so i am planning to use thread.sleep ..

Answer (score 0):

why not

```
            while(!howeverYouWantToCheckIfFound){
            try{
             thread.sleep(1000);}Catch(exception e){}
            }
```

Comment: Because it is not compilable.

Comment: wow how did you check the file.I mean what doesn't work here?

Answer (score 0):

Improving a bit the answer of @Madhan you can also set an interval to sleep between checking an element status. Do it like this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), TIME_OUT, TIME_TO_SLEEP);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("XPATH")));
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally like the `FluentWait` together with an `ExpectedCondition`. It can be configured pretty nice with the `ignoring` amd `pollingEvery` Methods

```
protected <T> T waitFor(ExpectedCondition<T> condition, String errorMessage) {
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                             .withTimeout(10, SECONDS)
                             .ignoring(NullPointerException.class)
                             .ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class)
                             .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
                             .ignoring(ElementNotVisibleException.class)
                             .ignoring(WebDriverException.class)
                             .pollingEvery(100, MILLISECONDS)
                             .withMessage(errorMessage);
T result = wait.until(condition);
return result;
}
```

it can be used like this:

```
waitFor(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(webElement),"Cannot click webElement");
```